# Is it possible to use SQL Update on a Sub Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is it possible to use the sql UPDATE on a sub query? I am using Big
Query Standard SQL and have tried every permutation of the below that I can come up with:

```
WITH test AS (SELECT * FROM 'my.database.table'),
test2 AS (UPDATE test SET myField = 100 WHERE myField < 100)
SELECT * FROM test2
```

I always receive the error:

> Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got
> keyword UPDATE

Comment: What is your end goal here? Why not just update table directly?

Comment: If your goal is to return everything from `my.database.table` but with a clamp on  `myField` so that it's always >= 100 then you can do that with a `CASE` clause in the selection list.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError
I marked the below as the answer because it best fit my use case.  However, I wanted to acknowledge that your answer would have worked just as well in my example. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below instead

```
with test as (
  select * from `my.database.table`
), test2 as (
  select * replace(greatest(myfield, 100) as myfield) from test 
)
select * from test2
```

Comment: There it is.  Thanks!